# How to test parallel, mocked data requests in JEST whilst simulating cached responses with a 500ms threshold

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, async-await, jestjs

The purpose of the tests is to mock parallel requests that fetch different sources of data. I introduce an artificial latency for each request and after some time return a simple string with an identifying digit to see if the data has been loaded from cache (requests within 500ms) or not. So for data loaded within 500ms the output should be "A1B1", else, after 500ms, it should be "A2B2" and so on.

```
// index.test.js
const { wait } = require('./util/wait.js');
const { requestAandB, requestBandC } = require('./index.js');

test('Test cache timings ', () => Promise.all([

  // send two requests in parallel after 0 ms (immediately)
  wait(0).then(() => Promise.all([
    expect(requestAandB()).resolves.toEqual('A1B1'),
    expect(requestBandC()).resolves.toEqual('B1C1'),
  ])),

  // send two requests in parallel after 480 ms
  wait(480).then(() => Promise.all([
    expect(requestAandB()).resolves.toEqual('A1B1'),
    expect(requestBandC()).resolves.toEqual('B1C1'),
  ])),

  // send two requests in parallel after 520 ms
  wait(520).then(() => Promise.all([
    expect(requestAandB()).resolves.toEqual('A2B2'),
    expect(requestBandC()).resolves.toEqual('B2C2'),
  ])),

]));
```

This is how I mock the data loads

```
// get-data.js

async function mockLoading(str) {
  // introduce some latency
  const waitDuration = Math.round(Math.random() * (WAIT_MAX - WAIT_MIN)) + WAIT_MIN;
  await wait(waitDuration);
  // create or increase counter every time the function is being called
  counters[str] = counters[str] === undefined ? 1 : counters[str] + 1;
  return str + counters[str];
}

module.exports = {
  loadDataA: async () => mockLoading('A'),
  loadDataB: async () => mockLoading('B'),
  loadDataC: async () => mockLoading('C'),
}
```

Finally, the implementation for the methods `requestAandB` and `requestBandC` imported in the test file:

```
const { loadDataA, loadDataB, loadDataC } = require('./model/get-data.js');
    
const all = Promise.all([loadDataA(), loadDataB(), loadDataC()])

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}  
   
async function requestAandB() {
  const temp = await all

  await delay(Math.random() * 510)
 
  return temp.filter((_, i) =>  i < 2).join("")

}

async function requestBandC() {
  const temp = await all
 
  await delay(Math.random() * 510)

  return temp.filter((_, i) => i > 0).join("") 

}

module.exports = { requestAandB, requestBandC }
```

Tests for the data "A1B1", "B1C1" are fine, but because the latency (in the `mockLoading` function) is always above the 500ms threshold, I am not able to get the right results for data returned after that. In effect, "A2B2" and "B2C2" always fail.

Does anyone know what am I missing here?

Comment: The problem in the implementation is that the three functions (`Promise.all([loadDataA(), loadDataB(), loadDataC()])
`) are called only once each once the module (`index.js`) is loaded

Comment: @Teneff and that isn't the only problem..valid point anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky problem indeed but I managed to crack it by doing the following:

1. Moving the `Promise.all` inside their respective functions; that is because the promise for the loadData functions was only called once on module load (thanks to @Teneff and @Observer for the hints)
2. Implementation of a cache function to cache the **intended promise** (not the intended outcome...), returning the loadData (cached) once some condition was met.

We did not need to change the `mockLoading` function at all. The OP required the implementation of client code, calling then external API's to simulate high variance across *n* number of asynchronous requests. Put it differently, we had to eliminate (or minimise) the risk of data collision for parallel asynchronous requests, and how to test some mocked cases in Jest.

Some code to make the whole process clearer:

```
const { loadDataA, loadDataB, loadDataC } = require('./model/get-data.js');

// we tackle this problem using memoization
// when `useCache` is called, we cache the loadData function name
// we then assign 1. a timestamp property to it and 2. a pointer to the promise itself

const CACHE_DURATION = 500;

const cache = {};
 function useCache(fn) {
   const cached = cache[fn.name];
   const now = Date.now();
   if (!cached || cached.ts < now - CACHE_DURATION) {
     cache[fn.name] = { ts: now, promise: fn() }
   }
   return cache[fn.name].promise;
 }
 
 async function requestAandB() {
   const [a, b] = await Promise.all([ loadDataA, loadDataB ].map(useCache));
   return a + b;
 }
 
 async function requestBandC() {
   const [b, c] = await Promise.all([ loadDataB, loadDataC ].map(useCache));
   return b + c;
 }

module.exports = { requestAandB, requestBandC }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first tests don't work properly as well.

> So for data loaded within 500ms the output should be "A1B1", else, after 500ms, it should be "A2B2" and so on.

But later you said

> Tests for the data "A1B1", "B1C1" are fine, but because the latency (in the mockLoading function) is always above the 500ms threshold, I am not able to get the right results for data returned after that. In effect, "A2B2" and "B2C2" always fail.

Easiest way will be to pass time to `requestAandB` and `requestBandC`, because using `Math.random()` can give you random numbers and might fail tests randomly. So try this approach:

```
test('Test cache timings ', () =>
  Promise.all([
    // send two requests in parallel after 0 ms (immediately)
    expect(requestAandB(0)).resolves.toEqual('A1B1'),
    expect(requestBandC(0)).resolves.toEqual('B1C1'),

    // send two requests in parallel after 480 ms
    expect(requestAandB(480)).resolves.toEqual('A1B1'),
    expect(requestBandC(480)).resolves.toEqual('B1C1'),

    // send two requests in parallel after 520 ms
    expect(requestAandB(520)).resolves.toEqual('A2B2'),
    expect(requestBandC(520)).resolves.toEqual('B2C2'),

    // send two requests in parallel after 360 ms
    expect(requestAandB(360)).resolves.toEqual('A1B1'),
    expect(requestBandC(360)).resolves.toEqual('B1C1'),

    // send two requests in parallel after 750 ms
    expect(requestAandB(750)).resolves.toEqual('A2B2'),
    expect(requestBandC(750)).resolves.toEqual('B2C2'),
  ]));
```

index.js

```
const { loadDataA, loadDataB, loadDataC } = require('./get-data.js');

async function requestAandB(time) {
  const temp = await Promise.all([
    loadDataA(time),
    loadDataB(time),
    loadDataC(time),
  ]); // don't use global Promise outside of this function

  return temp.filter((_, i) => i < 2).join('');
}

async function requestBandC(time) {
  const temp = await Promise.all([
    loadDataA(time),
    loadDataB(time),
    loadDataC(time),
  ]); // don't use global Promise outside of this function

  return temp.filter((_, i) => i > 0).join('');
}

module.exports = { requestAandB, requestBandC };
```

get-data.js

```
// get-data.js
const { wait } = require('./wait.js');

async function mockLoading(time, str) {
  await wait(time);

  // here is the logic if time is less then 500ms then append 1 else append 2
  let label = str;
  if (Math.ceil(time / 500) <= 1) {
     label += '1';
  } else {
     label += '2';
  }

  return label;
}

module.exports = {
  loadDataA: async time => mockLoading(time, 'A'),
  loadDataB: async time => mockLoading(time, 'B'),
  loadDataC: async time => mockLoading(time, 'C'),
};
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I have noticed you have changed the signature of the `loadData` functions. We have a constraint here because this is code we have no control over and thus, we cannot change it. We are **calling** this load methods and the `Math.random()` has been used to mock some latency.

Comment: further, you have placed some comments in the client code without briefly describing why I should not be using a "global" Promise outside the methods; a little note here, this is not strictly a global Promise, it is __not__ locally scoped to these functions, yes, but it is not global by definition since it is scoped inside the module. Semantics aside, why are you suggesting not to call the load data Promises outside the methods?

Comment: I must agree with you that tests for A1B1 and B1C1 are also flaky, yes.

Comment: `await wait(waitDuration);
  counters[str] = counters[str] === undefined ? 1 : counters[str] + 1;
  return str + counters[str];`

Just in case it was not clear, `wait` is a Promise that always resolves, after a random amount of time, with the `str + counters[str]`  string

Comment: If you will use random `waitDuration` then your tests will fail no matter what. Sometimes they might work and sometimes might not, because you don't know when random `waitDuration` will be more or less than 500ms. I meant "global" scope to that module, not to a function. If you will use "global" scope to that module, then you will have all the time `A1B1` and `B1C1` results.

Comment: Also, with random `waitDuration` you might have the following combinations: `A1B2`, `A2B1`, `B2C1`, `B1C2`

Comment: That is exactly the point of developing this functionality, mocking I/O requests over the network, where latency is highly unpredictable (e.g. where the level of variance across requests is particularly high).  As to simulate the randomness of data requests from several API's, Math.random() satisfies the model at the problem level so, I am fairly happy with that.